# ImportError: cannot import name 'Page'

Tags: python, django, otree

I have written a game in an Otree Project, but every time i want to clean my database or start the server, this message appears. It only happens with my game, but not when an example game is using that command.[image]

Comment: Please do not post errors as images

Comment: is your `_builtin` file parallel to `views.py` ?

Comment: what version of oTree do you use? The code was apparently written in a pretty old version of oTree (since a new one uses `pages.py` not `views.py`). And if you use a new version with this code it can be due version incompatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your app for the folder `_builtin`. There should be a file `__init__.py` that has the same contents as every other app's `_builtin/__init__.py`. If not, copy it from the other app.